# Llamar una función propia al hacer clic en la equis (x) del autocomplete de Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs

¿Cómo puedo ejecutar una función hecha por mí al hacer clic en la equis (x) que limpia el autocomplete de Angular Material?

[Enlace al demo de autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)

Código tomado tal cual de [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)

HTML:

```
<md-autocomplete
      ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
      md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
      md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
      md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
      md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
      md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
      md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
      md-item-text="item.display"
      md-min-length="0"
      placeholder="What is your favorite US state?">
    <md-item-template>
      <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
      No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
      <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
    </md-not-found>
  </md-autocomplete>
```

.js:

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('autocompleteDemo', ['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

  function DemoCtrl ($timeout, $q, $log) {
    var self = this;

    self.simulateQuery = false;
    self.isDisabled    = false;

    // list of `state` value/display objects
    self.states        = loadAll();
    self.querySearch   = querySearch;
    self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
    self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;

    self.newState = newState;

    function newState(state) {
      alert("Sorry! You'll need to create a Constitution for " + state + " first!");
    }

    // ******************************
    // Internal methods
    // ******************************

    /**
     * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
     * remote dataservice call.
     */
    function querySearch (query) {
      var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states,
          deferred;
      if (self.simulateQuery) {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
      } else {
        return results;
      }
    }

    function searchTextChange(text) {
      $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
    }

    function selectedItemChange(item) {
      $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
    }

    /**
     * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
     */
    function loadAll() {
      var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
              Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
              Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
              Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
              North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
              South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
              Wisconsin, Wyoming';

      return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
        return {
          value: state.toLowerCase(),
          display: state
        };
      });
    }

    /**
     * Create filter function for a query string
     */
    function createFilterFor(query) {
      var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

      return function filterFn(state) {
        return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
      };

    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Está demasiado ambiguo lo que estás planteando, tienes el código que estás usando o algún demo dónde poder verlo en línea?

Comment: Creo que ese botón es agregado por la directiva y no me parece que puedas quitarlo o controlarlo.

Comment: @Alex disculpa si mi pregunta te parece ambigua, desde mi punto de vista no lo es. Imagina que copias y pegas el código desde el enlace que publiqué. Cómo puedo hacer para ejecutar una función definida por mí al hacer clic en el botón que limpia el autocomplete de Angular Material.

Comment: estoy imaginando con toda energía que copio y pego, pero no ocurre nada. Podrías tú, pf, hacerlo, para que todos los que vemos tu pregunta podamos entender qué estás haciendo.

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta. De antemano, les agradezco la excelente ayuda que me podrán brindar.

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas en el código que renderiza el md-autocomplete, el botón X tiene este atributo

```
ng-click="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.clear($event)"
```

Por lo que no creo que puedas sobreescribir la funcionalidad de ese ng-click si ya está llamando internamente a su servicio propio $mdAutocompleteCtrl.

Buscando una posible solución a tu problema, me he fijado un poco en que a la carga, el md-autocomplete tiene estas clases:

```
class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty ng-valid-required"
```

Cuando introducimos un valor tiene estas otras:

```
class="ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-required ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched"
```

Y cuando pulsamos el botón de borrar, estas:

```
class="ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-touched ng-empty"
```

### Solución

Usando el atributo del autocomplete `md-search-text-change` junto con las propiedades del ng-model como `$pristine` o `$dirty` podemos realizar un hack para conseguir lo que quieres por otro medio.

Primeramente, en el html:

```
md-search-text-change="$ctrl.checkIfAutoCompleteIsClear()"
md-search-text="$ctrl.text"
ng-model="$ctrl.foo.bar"
```

En tu controlador:

```
this.checkIfAutoCompleteIsClear = () => {
  if (this.text === '' && this.foo.bar.$dirty) {
    ejecutarTuFunción();
  }
};
```

Básicamente le estamos diciendo, que cuando el texto esté vacío y el modelo esté $dirty, es cuando realmente el botón ha sido pulsado, por lo que ejecutaremos tu función después de comprobarlo.